# How can I make many pings asynchronously at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ping

I just can't seem to understand how to structure an asynchronous call to SendPingAsync. I want to loop through a list of IP addresses and ping them all asynchronously before moving on in the program... right now it takes forever to go through all of them one at a time. I asked a question about it earlier thinking I'd be able to figure out async but apparently I was wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PingLoop();
    MessageBox.Show("hi"); //for testing

}

public async void PingLoop()
{
    Task<int> longRunningTask = PingAsync();

    int result = await longRunningTask;
    MessageBox.Show("async call is finished!"); 

    //eventually want to loop here but for now just want to understand how this works
}

private async Task<int> PingAsync()
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    string reply = pingSender.SendPingAsync("www.google.com", 2000).ToString();
    pingReplies.Add(reply); //what should i be awaiting here?? 
    return 1;
}
```

I'm afraid I just don't get what is really going on here enough... when should I return a task? When I run this as is I just get a frozen UI and a ping error. I have read the MSDN documentation and tons of questions here and I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd want to do something like:

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
    var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

This will start off one request per IP in `theListOfIPs` asynchronously, then asynchronously wait for them all to complete.  It will then return the list of replies.

Note that it's almost always better to return the results vs. setting them in a field, as well.  The latter can lead to bugs if you go to use the field (`pingReplies`) before the asynchronous operation completes - by returning, and adding the range to your collection after the call is made with `await`, you make the code more clear and less bug prone.

Comment: I had to modify "ip => pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000)" to ip => new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 2000) otherwise it would throw "System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method"

Comment: What is theListOfIPs ?

Comment: @softwareisfun A List<string> of IPs.

Answer (score 2):

What you do here `pingSender.SendPingAsync("www.google.com", 2000).ToString();` doesn't make much sense.

Instead you should return `pingSender.SendPingAsync("www.google.com", 2000)` and

`await Task.WhenAll(your all ping requests)`

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to start all pings at once:

```
var pingTargetHosts = ...; //fill this in
var pingTasks = pingTargetHosts.Select(
     host => new Ping().SendPingAsync(host, 2000)).ToList();
```

Now the pings are running. Collect their results:

```
var pingResults = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
```

Now the concurrent phase of the processing is done and you can examine and process the results.

Comment: Why `ToList()` on the pingTasks if your just going to use it with WhenAll anyways?

Comment: @ReedCopsey habit, to get more reliable side-effects. I might later enumerate `pingTasks` again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it

```
private delegate void scanTargetDelegate(IPAddress ipaddress);

private Task<PingReply> pingAsync(IPAddress ipaddress)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PingReply>();
        try
        {

            AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            Ping ping = new Ping();
            ping.PingCompleted += (obj, sender) =>
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(sender.Reply);
                };
            ping.SendAsync(ipaddress, new object { });

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

in a BackgroundWorker I do this

```
List<Task<PingReply>> pingTasks = new List<Task<PingReply>>();

        addStatus("Scanning Network");
        foreach (var ip in range)
        {
            pingTasks.Add(pingAsync(ip));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(pingTasks.ToArray());

        addStatus("Network Scan Complete");

        scanTargetDelegate d = null;
        IAsyncResult r = null;

foreach (var pingTask in pingTasks)
        {
            if (pingTask.Result.Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success))
            {
                d = new scanTargetDelegate(scanTarget); //do something with the ip
                r = d.BeginInvoke(pingTask.Result.Address, null, null);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref Global.queuedThreads);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!ownIPs.Contains(pingTask.Result.Address))
                {
                    failed.Add(pingTask.Result.Address);
                }
            }
        }

        if (r != null)
        {
            WaitHandle[] waits = new WaitHandle[] { r.AsyncWaitHandle };
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(waits);
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to do that - `Ping` already supports async: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193994(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: well that makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<bool> PingAsync(string host)
{
    try
    {
        var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        var reply = await ping.SendTaskAsync(host);

        return (reply.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success);
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```