# Why simple multi task doesn't work when multi thread does?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, multitasking

```
var finalList = new List<string>();
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ................. 999999};

var init = 0;
var limitPerThread = 5;

var countDownEvent = new CountdownEvent(list.Count);

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var listToFilter = list.Skip(init).Take(limitPerThread).ToList();
    new Thread(delegate()
                   {
                       Foo(listToFilter);
                       countDownEvent.Signal();
                   }).Start();    
    init += limitPerThread;
}

//wait all to finish
countDownEvent.Wait();


private static void Foo(List<int> listToFilter)
{
    var listDone = Boo(listToFilter);
    lock (Object)
    {
        finalList.AddRange(listDone);
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var listToFilter = list.Skip(init).Take(limitPerThread).ToList();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Foo(listToFilter)); 
    taskList.add(task);   
    init += limitPerThread;
}

//wait all to finish
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

This process must create at least 700 threads in the end. When I run using Thread, it works and creates all of them. But with `Task` it doesn't.. It seems like its not starting multiples `Tasks` async.

I really wanna know why.... any ideas?

**EDIT**

Another version with **PLINQ** (as suggested).

```
var taskList = new List<Task>(list.Count);
Parallel.ForEach(taskList, t =>
                   {
                       var listToFilter = list.Skip(init).Take(limitPerThread).ToList();
                       Foo(listToFilter);
                       init += limitPerThread;
                       t.Start();
                   });
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

**EDIT2:**

```
public static List<Communication> Foo(List<Dispositive> listToPing)
{
    var listResult = new List<Communication>();
    foreach (var item in listToPing)
    {
        var listIps = item.listIps;
        var communication = new Communication
        {
            IdDispositive = item.Id
        };

        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < listIps.Count(); i++)
            {
                var oPing = new Ping().Send(listIps.ElementAt(i).IpAddress, 10000);
                if (oPing != null)
                {
                    if (oPing.Status.Equals(IPStatus.TimedOut) && listIps.Count() > i+1)
                        continue;
                    if (oPing.Status.Equals(IPStatus.TimedOut))
                    {
                        communication.Result = "NOK"; 
                        break;
                    }
                    communication.Result = oPing.Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success) ? "OK" : "NOK";
                    break;
                }
                if (listIps.Count() > i+1)
                    continue;
                communication.Result = "NOK";
                break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            communication.Result = "NOK";
        }
        finally
        {
            listResult.Add(communication);
        }
    }

    return listResult;
}
```

Comment: Can you process the elements one-by-one? That is, can you call `Boo()` on a single element, and not a list?

Comment: I can't process them one-by-one.. it's a process to ping multiples ips address... I need to ping all of them (+- 3000) in less than 2 minutes. And I need to store the result.

Comment: Wait... just **what** does `Boo()` do, actually? It doesn't simply spawn a `ping` process, does it?

Comment: _This process must create at least 700 threads_ is of course ridiculous. That's wasting a Gig of committed Ram and requiring an awful lot of context switching.

Comment: @Vilx: Yes...That's exactly what it does... Henk, that's why I want to implement Tasks instead.. :)

Comment: Good, but then what is you measurement?  Number of threads or performance? They can/will be very different.

Comment: **MASSIVELY BAD** idea. It'll basically crash your computer. You don't spawn 3000 new processes and expect it to live. In the best case, your computer will come out of its agony an hour later; in the worst you'll have to reboot it by force.

Comment: Instead you should use the [`Ping` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx). That even has a `SendAsync()` method which is what you want.

Comment: Well... I just need to ping 3000 IPs every 3 minutes... So the entire process needs to run within 2 minutes at the most (to avoid trouble).

Comment: Try the Ping class. At the first attempt, don't even bother with multithreading. Just create 3000 `Task`s from the `SendAsync()` method and `WaitAll` on them. Chances are it will run in 10 seconds anyway.

Comment: A typical XY question. You asked about creating 700 Threads or 3000 Processes but your problem is "how to do a massive Ping". Answering Y wouldn't involve X.

Comment: I edited the question with `Boo()` method.... as I said in the question, I "solved" the problem but I'd like a better solution

Comment: The better solution is to use `Ping.SendAsync` with `await` and `async`. That way you won't spawn 3000 threads, you'll ping all the IPs from one thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task`s are NOT multithreading. They *can* be used for that, but mostly they're actually used for the opposite - multiplexing on a single thread.

To use tasks for multithreading, I suggest using [Parallel LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx). It has many optimizations in it already, such as intelligent partitioning of your lists and only spawning as many threads as there ar CPU cores, etc.

---

To understand `Task` and `async`, think of it this way - a typical workload often includes IO that needs to be waited upon. Maybe you read a file, or query a webservice, or access a database, or whatever. The point is - your thread gets to wait a loooong time (in CPU cycles at least) until you get a response from some faraway destination.

In the Olden Days™ that meant that your thread was getting locked down (suspended) until that response came. If you wanted to do something else in the meantime, you needed to spawn a new thread. That's doable, but not too efficient. Each OS thread carries a significant overhead (memory, kernel resources) with it. And you could end up with several threads actively burning the CPU, which means that the OS needs to switch between them so that each gets a bit of CPU time and these "context switches" are pretty expensive.

`async` changes that workflow. Now you can have multiple workloads executing on the same thread. While one piece of work is `await`ing the result from a faraway source, another can step in and use that thread to do something else useful. When that second workload gets to its own `await`, the first can awaken and continue.

After all, **it doesn't make sense to spawn more threads than there are CPU cores**. You're not going to get more work done that way. Just the opposite - more time will be spent on switching the threads and less time will be available for useful work.

That is what the `Task`/`async`/`await` was originally designed for. However Parallel LINQ has also taken advantage of it and reused it for multithreading. In this case you can look at it this way - the other threads is what your main thread is the "faraway destination" that your main thread is waiting on.

Comment: good text, bro... I tried PLINQ too but without success.. i'm going to edit the question within the implementation. I appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: "Tasks are NOT multithreading" - No, not always but StartNew() does mean pushing them out to the ThreadPool at least.

Comment: True, but it's a common misconception that async == multithreading. And it seems that the OP thought so too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `StartNew` uses `Current` sync context, which can be a UI one, so the task wouldn't be sent to the ThreadPool

Answer (score 5):

Tasks are executed on the Thread Pool.  This means that a handful of threads will serve a large number of tasks.  You have multi-threading, but not a thread for every task spawned.

You should use tasks.  You should aim to use as much threads as your CPU.  Generally, the thread pool is doing this for you.

Answer (score 0):

How did you measure up the performance? Do you think that the `700` threads will work faster than `700` tasks executing by `4` threads? No, they would not.

> It seems like its not starting multiples Tasks async

How did you came up with this? As other suggested in comments and in other answers, you probably need to remove a thread creation, as after creating `700` threads you'll degrade your system performance, as your threads would fight to each other for the processor time, without any work done faster.

So, you need to add the `async/await` for your IO operations, into the `Foo` method, with [`SendPingAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159556.aspx) version. Also, your method could be simplyfied, as many checks for a `listIps.Count() > i + 1` conditions  are useless - you do it in the `for` condition block:

```
public static async Task<List<Communication>> Foo(List<Dispositive> listToPing)
{
    var listResult = new List<Communication>();
    foreach (var item in listToPing)
    {
        var listIps = item.listIps;
        var communication = new Communication
        {
            IdDispositive = item.Id
        };

        try
        {
            var ping = new Ping();
            communication.Result = "NOK";

            for (var i = 0; i < listIps.Count(); i++)
            {
                var oPing = await ping.SendPingAsync(listIps.ElementAt(i).IpAddress, 10000);
                if (oPing != null)
                {
                    if (oPing.Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        communication.Result = "OK";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            communication.Result = "NOK";
        }
        finally
        {
            listResult.Add(communication);
        }
    }

    return listResult;
}
```

Other problem with your code is that `PLINQ` version isn't threadsafe:

```
init += limitPerThread;
```

This can fail while executing in parallel. You may introduce some helper method, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078703/213550):

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<Communication> theListOfIPs)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 10000));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

And do this kind of check (`try/catch` logic removed for simplicity):

```
public static async Task<List<Communication>> Foo(List<Dispositive> listToPing)
{
    var listResult = new List<Communication>();
    foreach (var item in listToPing)
    {
        var listIps = item.listIps;
        var communication = new Communication
        {
            IdDispositive = item.Id
        };
        var check = await PingAsync(listIps);
        communication.Result = check.Any(p => p.Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success)) ? "OK" : "NOK";
     }
 }
```

And you probably should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.StartNew` for being sure that you aren't blocking the UI thread.