# c# - wpf - Main UI hang during execution of Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'am using WPF with multi threading. Problem is during execution of the MAIN thread hangs, like its waiting for something or infinite loop in main UI. I don't know if there's any other approach when it comes to multi threading in WPF. See my code below:

```
Thread myNewThread1 = new Thread(() => ping(IP1, img_m));
Thread myNewThread2 = new Thread(() => ping(IP2, img_h));
Thread myNewThread3 = new Thread(() => ping(IP3, img_c));
Thread myNewThread4 = new Thread(() => ping(IP4, img_b));
Thread myNewThread5 = new Thread(() => ping(IP5, img_e));

myNewThread1.Start();
myNewThread2.Start();
myNewThread3.Start();
myNewThread4.Start();
myNewThread5.Start();


private void ping(string IP, Image img)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        var r = p.Send(IP, 1000, new byte[5]);

        if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();

            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri("subonline.gif", UriKind.Relative);
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.EndInit();
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
        }
        else
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();

            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri("suboffline.gif", UriKind.Relative);
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.EndInit();
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
        }
    });

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    ping(IP, img);
}
```

Comment: use `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Instead of using threads (or any other selfmade background processing), better take a look at PingAsync and PingCompleted.

Comment: HI guys thanks for your reply i switch to backgroundworker and its working fine now :)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal `BackgroundWorker` is very obsolete approach, and you should avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread hangs because of `Dispatcher.Invoke` wrong usage, it should be used for UI logic only, so you should move out the `Ping`-oriented logic out of it.

Do not use the `BackgroundWorker` for this, it's an obsolete and heavy construction you don't really need. Also, do not a thread for pinging, this is wrong approach, and that's why:

Pinging operation is network-related, and the thread you're using for **wait** the remote server to response simply wastes the system resources, as it does **absolutely nothing** except wait. So you should switch to asynchronous approach for this.

You either should subscribe to [`Ping.PingCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.pingcompleted.aspx) event and call the [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync.aspx) method, like this:

```
private void ping(string IP, MediaTypeNames.Image img)
{
    Ping p = new Ping();
    PingReply r;
    // lambda delegate here, may use event handler instead
    p.PingCompleted += (sender, args) => { PingCompleted(args, img); };
    r = p.SendAsync(IP, 1000, new byte[5], null);
}

private void PingCompleted(PingCompletedEventArgs args, MediaTypeNames.Image img)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            string imageAddress;
            if (args.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                imageAddress = "subonline.gif";
            }
            else
            {
                imageAddress = "suboffline.gif";
            }

            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri(imageAddress, UriKind.Relative);
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.EndInit();
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
        });
}
```

or you should use `async/await` feature which was introduced exactly for such cases (code partially from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078703/213550)):

```
// async event handler
private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // async call to all the ips
    var results = await PingAsync(new List<string> { IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, IP5 });
    // here we do not need the Dispatcher as await will restore UI context for you
   PingCompleted(results[0], img_m);
   // etc
}

private void PingCompleted(PingReply r, MediaTypeNames.Image img)
{
    string imageAddress;
    if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        imageAddress = "subonline.gif";
    }
    else
    {
        imageAddress = "suboffline.gif";
    }

    var image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.UriSource = new Uri(imageAddress, UriKind.Relative);
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.EndInit();
    ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
}

// helper method
private async Task<PingReply[]> PingAsync(List<string> theListOfIPs)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tasks = theListOfIPs.Select(ip => pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 1000, new byte[5]));
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the call to p.Send method in the dispatcher - currently only the Thread.Sleep(500) is done in the background and everything else is done in the UI thread.

Also, I believe that because of the Thread.Sleep the function never gives the UI thread a chance to work so the pinging never occurs. Replace the use of Thread.Sleep with a Thread.Timer object.