# Accessing value used in LINQ Select within a foreach

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Given a list of IP addresses:

```
List<string> ipList = new List<string>(); //example: 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3 etc.
```

I am attempting to loop over each IP in the list, in a parallel fashion and then print a meaningful message to screen:

```
foreach (PingReply pingReply in ipList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(64).Select(ip => new Ping().Send(ip)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ping status: {pingReply.Status} for the target IP address: {ip}");
}
```

I am unable to access `ip` in that context. I would really like to understand how I could go about accessing each *relative* `ip` as I am sending them out?

I have explored the [`PingReply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.address?view=net-5.0) object but [`PingReply.Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.address?view=net-5.0#System_Net_NetworkInformation_PingReply_Address) as an example contains the host (sender) IP, so it cannot help with this requirement. I really wish the `PingReply` object contained the Ip that was pinged!

---

### **UPDATE**

As per example provided by @haim770 and @MindSwipe I ended up using:

```
foreach (var pingResponseData in ipList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(64).Select(ip => new { ip, pingReply = new Ping().Send(ip) }))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ping status: {pingResponseData.pingReply.Status} for the target IP address: {pingResponseData.ip}");
}
```

---

### **UPDATE 2**

As per comment from @pinkfloydx33 regarding use of `ValueTuple` I have done as per the following example:

```
foreach (var (ip, reply) in ipList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(ipList.Count).Select(ip => (ip, new Ping().Send(ip, 150))))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ping status: {reply.Status} for the target IP address: {ip}");
}
```

Comment: Just use `.Select(ip => new { ip, pingResult = new Ping().Send(ip) })`

Comment: Use `Parallel.ForEach(ipList, ip => { /*code to do ping and write result*/ });` instead. it will be easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @haim770! You response makes sense and worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently only selecting the `pingReply`, not the `ip` and the `pingReply`, to do that you'll need to select a new [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) and iterate over that. Like so:

```cs
foreach (var (pingReply, ip) in ipList.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(64).Select(ip => (ip, Ping().Send(ip))))
{
    // Here 'i' is an object with the properties 'ip' and 'pingReply'
    Console.WriteLine($"Ping status: {i.pingReply.Status} for the target IP address: {i.ip}");
}
```

---

**Edit:** Just noticed now that [haim770](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770) posted basically this in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220520/accessing-value-used-in-linq-select-within-a-foreach/66220707?noredirect=1#comment117075060_66220520)

**Edit 2:** Thanks [pinkfloydx33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491907/pinkfloydx33) for pointing out I could use [tuple deconsturcting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct)

Comment: Thanks for the example @MindSwipe! Makes sense. (P.S. just double check your example there was a typo with lack of closing `}`

Comment: Ah thanks @BernardV, didn't notice the missing closing brace as I'm sitting in School right now. I edited the answer. Also make sure to accept my answer if it answers your question, so future readers know it worked out (comments have a tendency to not stick around)

Comment: If you select a `ValueTuple` instead you can destructure it in the `foreach`... It might be clearer `foreach (var (ip, reply) in ipList.XXX.Select(ip => (ip, new Ping().Send(ip)))) { Console.WriteLine($"status {reply.Status} - ip {ip}“); }`

Comment: Ah yeah thanks @pinkfloydx33, I technically know that, but my brain blanked. I'll edit my question once I get to a computer

Answer (score 0):

Calling the synchronous `Ping.Send` in parallel with a degree of parallelism = 64 is quite inefficient, because as many as 64 threads are blocked during the parallel execution (provided that the `ThreadPool` has enough threads available to satisfy the demand, which is doubtful). A more efficient way to do the pinging is to use the asynchronous [`Ping.SendPingAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync) method. To invoke this method in a way that no more than 64 asynchronous operations will be simultaneously in-flight, you will need a `Parallel.ForEach` equivalent that works with asynchronous delegates. Currently there is no such thing available built-in (it will probably [be available](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946) in .NET 6), but you can find lots of custom implementations if you search for `ForEachAsync`. There is one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/65251949#65251949) for example. Then you will be able to do this:

```
var ipList = new List<string>() {"192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3"}; // etc

ipList.ForEachAsync(async ip =>
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip);
    Console.WriteLine($"IP '{ip}' ping reply status: {reply.Status}");
}, dop: 64).Wait();
```

You could also `await` the completion of the operation, instead of using the blocking `Wait`, provided that you are calling it from an `async` method.

Comment: Thank you @Theodor Zoulias I will explore your recommendation; before settling on `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism` method I did explore the async ping method through example like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078703/3324415 but it for some reason did not feel any faster to complete the whole task (I am pining about 254 ip's).

Comment: if you are at all interested in looking at the little console app, I have it up here https://github.com/BVisagie/Live-Host-Sweeper; appreciate your feedback on my question thanks!

Comment: @BernardV I can't explain why it's not faster. There may be some other limiting factor, like some internal maximum number of simultaneous pings per domain. I don't know, just guessing.

Comment: Hi @Theodor Zoulias I have implemented your suggestion and it does seem to be very fast, I was wondering if anything could be done due to the nature of ordering of the results, I am assuming not due to not being in control of task completion? I have an online example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jZrrjy

Comment: @BernardV I guess you want to get the `PingReply` results in the same order with the IPs in the source list. In that case you probably need a version of `ForEachAsync` that offers a similar functionality with the `.AsParallel().AsOrdered()` PLINQ configuration. It's a pity that the built-in parallel libraries are not async-enabled yet, and we must use custom solutions, or write our own. You can find such an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations/64455549#64455549).